# How can I configure uncrustify to force one space after "struct"?

Tags: c, uncrustify

How can I configure uncrustify to change this:

```
struct     point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

into this?:

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Notice that the extra spaces between `struct` and `point` are removed.  I have spent a lot of time reading through the config options and I can't figure this one out.